# The Simplifier vs The Snitch

Tags: agricola, agricola-goodies

*We played with Agricola: The Goodies for the first time last night, and while it was very silly, it didn't have the negative impact on gameplay that I'd feared.  However, the Occupation cards from the L-deck created all sorts of rules questions for us that we weren't quite equipped to answer.  But that's where this site comes in!*

The Simplifier occupation reads:

> Occupations with more than 4 lines of
>   text have no effect for the remainder
>   of the game.

The Snitch has about 9 lines of text in total, but begins:

> Immediately flip 1 Occupation that you
>   have played face down.

In last night's rather crazy all-Goodies game of Agricola, one of the players played the Simplifier, to switch off the damn Bean Farmer for a while, but then played the Snitch to flip her own Simplifer, and reinstate the Bean Farmer.  (I never played an Occupation or Minor Improvement in the whole game because of all these shenanigans!)

The $1 million dollar question is of course, can you really flip the Simplifier with the Snitch, or is he unSnitchable?  (It seemed more fun to allow it at the time, but this type of thing is what keeps me awake at night!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snitch would have to be **valid** to undo Simplifier...and the Simplifier card text states that it has no effect for the rest of the game...

So...no **Snitching** for the **Simpleton**!

Comment: I would agree that this is the most sensible reading of the cards.  On the other hand, when you're playing with Goodies the word "sensible" doesn't necessarily apply any more! :D